# Order table by last name by ASC or DESC order

Tags: javascript, html

The problem I'm having is that the table isn't ordering correctly in ASC or DESC order.

The way it should work is if you click the Up or Down arrow it should re order the table values in the right order.

**What i've got so far:**

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
<thead>
     <tr>
       <th class="sortable orderNameByASC">Patients</th>
       <th>Pathway Date</th>
       <th>Discharge Date</th>
       <th class="showAllTeam">Team Name</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>                                   
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Up and Down Arrow in CSS**

```
#dataTables-example th.orderNameByASC:after
{
    content:'▲';
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 .5em;
    color:green;
}

#dataTables-example th.orderNameByDESC:after
{
    content:'▼';
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 .5em;
    color:green;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".sortable").click(function()
{
    var clickedSorting = $(this).hasClass('orderNameByASC') ? 'orderNameByDESC' : 'orderNameByASC';
    $('.sortable').removeClass('orderNameByASC').removeClass('orderNameByDESC');
    $(this).addClass(clickedSorting);

    var columnIndex = $(this).prevAll().length;
    var tableBody = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody");
    var tableRow = tableBody.find("tr");

    tableRow.sort(function(a, b)
    {   
        console.log($(a).find("td").eq(columnIndex).text().substr(0, $(a).find("td").eq(columnIndex).text().indexOf(' ')));
        var A = $(a).find("td").eq(columnIndex).text().substr(0, $(a).find("td").eq(columnIndex).text().indexOf(' '));
        var B = $(b).find("td").eq(columnIndex).text().substr(0, $(b).find("td").eq(columnIndex).text().indexOf(' '));

        if (!isNaN(A)) A = Number(A);
        if (!isNaN(B)) B = Number(B);

        return clickedSorting == 'orderNameByASC' ? A > B : B > A;
    });

    $.each(tableRow, function(key, value)
    {
        tableBody.append(value);
    });
});
```

**Order in ASC output**

```
Nettie Allen (03742739747)
Amy Clark 
George Allen (0866423839)
Baby Clark
Ann Baker (64636596952)
Baby Baker (07534799622)
Samantha Bond (0119293625)
Baby Bond (02764820182)
Ann Butler (7524575766)
Nicole Campbell (9373736281)
Peter Campbell (8257483511)
```

**Order in DESC output:**

```
Nicole Campbell (9373736281)
Peter Campbell (8257483511)
Nettie Allen (03742739747)
George Allen (0866423839)
Ann Baker (64636596952)
Baby Baker (07534799622)
Samantha Bond (0119293625)
Ann Butler (7524575766)
Baby Bond (02764820182)
Amy Clark
```

**Fiddle with example data:**

https://jsfiddle.net/zr7x1rk6/

Comment: Your sort function shouldn't return `true` or `false` (`A > B`, etc.) it should return `-1`, `0`, or `1`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Also, you seem to be doing a numeric comparison, when your problem statement involves sorting by *name*. Why the `Number()` conversion?

Comment: @PaulRoub The numbers are an ID which I need to show in the table, That why I use `substr()` to remove the numbers while I'm sorting.

Comment: Right, but as it is, you were trying to *sort* by converting the first name into a number. That can't possibly be what you meant to do.

Comment: Nope I wasn't trying to do that, that's why I came on to ask for the help of somebody else :) - Thank you for showing me my mistake. How would I go about doing it by last name?

Comment: See my answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're attempting a numeric comparison on strings. Don't do that.
2. You need to return -1, 0 or 1, not `true` or `false`
3. You're retrieving the *first* name, not the *last* name.

Instead:

```js
$(".sortable").click(function() {
  var clickedSorting = $(this).hasClass('orderNameByASC') ? 'orderNameByDESC' : 'orderNameByASC';
  $('.sortable').removeClass('orderNameByASC').removeClass('orderNameByDESC');
  $(this).addClass(clickedSorting);

  var columnIndex = $(this).prevAll().length;
  var tableBody = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody");
  var tableRow = tableBody.find("tr");

  tableRow.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aText = $(a).find("td").eq(columnIndex).text();
    var bText = $(b).find("td").eq(columnIndex).text();

    // get the last name. May need to do something more complicated
    // if you want to skip middle names
    var A = aText.substr(aText.indexOf(' '));
    var B = bText.substr(bText.indexOf(' '));

    if (clickedSorting == 'orderNameByASC')
      return A.localeCompare(B);
    else
      return B.localeCompare(A);
  });

  $.each(tableRow, function(key, value) {
    tableBody.append(value);
  });
});
```

```css
#dataTables-example th.orderNameByASC:after {
  content: '▲';
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: green;
}
#dataTables-example th.orderNameByDESC:after {
  content: '▼';
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sortable orderNameByASC">Patients</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Amy Clark (9655382022)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Baby Clark (08653271111)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lisa Cook (6395768765)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane Cooper (835251946)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jasmine Gill (7528696977)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Javier Romero (62794639279)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Baby baby Floyd (75211256890)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Baby Gill (8644790977)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, This is what I needed help with.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i am a bit late since Paul has already contributed his result first. Still, here is another way of doing your sort (now the names are sorted by lastname first and then by firstname). Maybe you can still find some interesting points here.

```js
$('#down').change(function(){ var 
 desc=$(this).prop('checked')?-1:1; // ascending or descending order?                       
 arr=$.makeArray($('table tr'));
 arr.sort(function(a,b){
  // local name extrating function: x is the tr-DOM element
  var n=function(x){var ar=$('td:eq(0)',x).text()
                           .toLowerCase().split(' ');
                    return ar[1]+ar[0];};
  var aa=n(a), bb=n(b);
  return aa==bb? 0 : (aa>bb ? 1 : -1)*desc;
 });
 $('table').html(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="down">descending order
<table>
<tr><td>Nettie Allen</td><td>(03742739747)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Amy Clark</td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><td>George Allen</td><td>(0866423839)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Baby Clark</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Ann Baker</td><td>(64636596952)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Baby Baker</td><td>(07534799622)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Samantha Bond</td><td>(0119293625)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Baby Bond</td><td>(02764820182)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Ann Butler</td><td>(7524575766)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Nicole Campbell</td><td>(9373736281)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Peter Campbell</td><td>(8257483511)</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes Paul's answer helped me out, but I'll still take a look at yours and take in the information. Always good to see different ways of working and thank you still for providing an answer